# CI pipeline in TFS for two different projects within the one pipeline

Tags: tfsbuild

I am having code in tfs repo,it has only master branch.In that master branch i am having 5 subfolders.one of the subfolders have the web app project(MVC+angular) and another have web api project(MVC+angular).All these are build with .net i.e with .sln file.can you guys give the idea for building pipeline for both web app and web api with that .sln file.

Comment: Do you mean you have two projects in one solution? And want to build the two projects in one pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a pipeline to build the solution, if the two projects in the same solution. If you want to trigger CI build for the two projects, you can specify [file paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) to include the two folders:

```
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - docs/*
    exclude:
    - docs/README.md
```

[image]